# How to do ssh login without a password and a public key?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I know how to enable ssh login without password by copy public key to remote server:

`cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'`

Is it possible to login to a remote server without password and public key?

In fact now I have two servers, `A` and `B`

there is only a `.ssh/id_rsa` in `A`, and there is no `.ssh/authorized_keys` in `B`, but I can login to `B` from `A` without password.

The person who setup this has quit, so I don't know how he did it.

Comment: You can try `ssh -v` to show the detailed process of authentication.

Comment: `debug1: Trying private key: /***/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).`

Comment: Your server seems to be doing public key authentication as normal. Please change the title to fit with it.

Comment: Pos the verbose log from the connection and from the server. It will answer all your questions. Also the ssh server configuration will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is probably configured with a different key search path.

Find the line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
```

If this is altered, the server will search different file(s) for the key.

EDIT: there's some more way to get authenticated with publickey.

Many config options starting with `Authorized` has the effect.

From the manual:

```
 AuthorizedKeysCommand
         Specifies a program to be used to look up the user's public keys.
         The program must be owned by root, not writable by group or oth‐
         ers and specified by an absolute path.  Arguments to
         AuthorizedKeysCommand accept the tokens described in the TOKENS
         section.  If no arguments are specified then the username of the
         target user is used.

         The program should produce on standard output zero or more lines
         of authorized_keys output (see AUTHORIZED_KEYS in sshd(8)).  If a
         key supplied by AuthorizedKeysCommand does not successfully
         authenticate and authorize the user then public key authentica‐
         tion continues using the usual AuthorizedKeysFile files.  By
         default, no AuthorizedKeysCommand is run.
```

Comment: I only found this: `HostDsaKey /etc/ssh/dsa_keys`

Comment: If the option is not set, `.ssh/authorized_keys2` is also accepted. Does it exist?

Comment: No, there is no `AuthorizedKeysFile  **` entry in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file nor `.ssh/authorized_keys2` file

Comment: Please check for other lines starting with Authorized.